# Generalise Pythagoras' Theorem to n things using *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, args

I have learnt one usually uses *arg arguments when you're not sure how many arguments might be passed to my function. I'm trying to create a generalised Pythagoras' theorem such that it computes for n things such that with

```
pytha(*arg)
```

with

```
print(pytha(x,y)) = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
print(pytha(x,y,z)) = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
print(pytha(x,z)) = np.sqrt(x**2 + z**2)
print(pytha(x-7,y)) = np.sqrt((x-7)**2 + y**2)
print(pytha(x-3,y-5,z-8)) = np.sqrt((x-3)**2 + (y-5)**2 + (z-8)**2)
print(pytha(x,y,z,t)) = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2 + t**2)
```

I've done

```
def pytha(*arg):
```

but I don't know how to manipulate *arg within the body of the functions. So how would one go about creating this function with *arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments you provide will get stored in the tuple with name you provided during function defining. If it is `*arg` then the tuple will be `arg` and you can then use it with that name.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def pytha(*arg):
...     v = [i**2 for i in arg]   # collected all in one list
...     return np.sqrt(sum(v))    # give argument by summing the list items
... 
>>> pytha(2,3,4)
5.385164807134504
```

Comment: would this work if 2 for loops in x and y is ran over pytha(x,y)?

Comment: Tested it and it does! Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is basically the same as @Vicrobot's, without using `numpy`. You can iterate over `arg` and calculate the square value of each element and then take the square root of the sum of those values:

```
import math

def pytha(*arg):
    return math.sqrt(sum(elem**2 for elem in arg))
```

Comment: So does your method not use a list at all then?

Comment: It does use a list comprehension to get the square of each elements, so yes, it uses a list.